# Create and Copy a select box with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, clone

We want to make a new select box and copy its options from another select box when an event happens. We use below code:

```
//Create a new select box and add it to a div
$('#content').append("<select id='destination'/>");
//Create copy source options
var $options = $("#source > option").clone();
//Append source option to destination
$("#destination").append($options);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e8ctkkvL/1/

I have a page with lots of selects(each with lots of options), above code is slow ! Is there any way I can make above JS faster ?!

Comment: I would clone `source` (and change its ID) rather than clone each individual option. You should change ID to a dynamic ID (or remove it altogether) to prevent duplicates

Comment: Example: http://jsfiddle.net/httcg2zb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather copy the source and set a dynamic id since you may want to have multiple select boxes and different IDs, like below:

Demo@[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e8ctkkvL/5/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var id = 1;
    $("#btn").click(function () {
        //Create a new select box
        $('#content').append($("#source").clone(true).attr({id: "destination" + id}));
        id++;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set a class instead of an ID and then append it to the last created select, for example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn").click(function () {
        //Create a new select box
        $('#content').append("<select class='destination'/>");
        //Create copy source options
        var $options = $("#source > option").clone();
        //Append source option to destination
        $(".destination").last().append($options);
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e8ctkkvL/3/